# SQLite give column not found error when there is not such named column

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am working on a parser with the help of Pandas and Sqlalchemy using sqlite database. I am reading from a file and assigning the values into columns.

```
dataFrame = pd.read_fwf('gf1401.gam',colspecs=colspaces,skiprows=37,nrows=1764)
dataFrame.columns=['elem','index','E','J','label','glande']
dataFrame['glande']=dataFrame['glande'].map(lambda x: '%1.3f' % x)
print dataFrame.head()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///dab.sqlite')
conn = engine.raw_connection()
dataFrame.to_sql(name='parser', con=conn, if_exists='append')
```

Now the last line gives a strange error namely 
`sqlite3.OperationalError: table parser has no column named level_0`

This is how I have created the db using sqlalchemy

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///dab.sqlite', echo=True)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Float
class parser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parser'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    elem = Column(String)
    index = Column(Integer)
    E = Column(Numeric)
    J = Column(Float)
    label = Column(String)
    glande = Column(Numeric)


parser.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

As you can see I don't even have a column named level 0.
Please help.
I have not used the id column in pandas because sqlite automatically inserts values for primary keys.
All I want is to insert data from the dataframe to a sqlite db and add a column which can act as a primary key

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the index column you already have. Pandas tries to insert the index of the dataframe as a column 'index', but as there is already an column named 'index', it uses a next option, namely 'level_0'. But as you append to the table, this column is not present. Possibly this is a bug in pandas, but there are some workarounds for now.

Possible workarounds for now are:

- specify to not insert the index of the dataframe: `dataFrame.to_sql(...., index=False)`
- specifying the column name in which the index should be inserted (if this is desired): `dataFrame.to_sql(...., index_label='id')`
- or you can let `to_sql` create the database table itself (no append), then table definition in python is not needed.

Comment: If I use the third option how will I later specify a primary key?
As far as I know sqlite doesn't allow altering a table to declare a primary key

Comment: @AmolAgrawal The index (or multi-index) of your dataframe is set as a primary key in sql, but at this moment there is not yet a way to customize this (see also https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7984)